# Regular Expression - certain digit from 4 character lines only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make regex that will find certain digit (to be more precisely - character "4") from block of lines that have only four characters: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or letter M (and later replace it, but I'll do it in notepad++).

I've got file with some characters like this:

```
2000
0400
01M0
0.476
0100
,
0000
14M0
0000
```

I want to find digit "4", but only in lines with four characters, so I'm interesed only with "4" from lines:

```
0400
14M0
```

I don't want "4" from line with 0.476. Also, four charater lines have only digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or letter M.

I tried, but ended only with expressions showing me whole lines with "4", such as:

> ^[0123M]{0,3}4+[0123M]{0,3}$
>
> ^[\dM]*4[\dM]*$

I can't extract only "4" from those lines. Tried some tutorials, but I'm too stupid ;) I can do it in two seperate regexes in some python script, but I would prefer to do it in notepad++ with one expression.

[EDIT]
Sorry I made this unclear.
I want to extract "4", to replace it with another digit ("2") in notepad++, ie. from
    0400
    14M0
to
    0200
    12M0

Comment: You want to "extract" a known digit? What for? Or do you need to keep the lines with that `4` and remove others?

Comment: Sorry I made this unclear, I've edited question. I want just to replace '4' with '2'.

Comment: Good, I provided an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*: `^(?=[0-4M]{4}$)([0-4M]*?)4`
*Replace with*: `${1}2`

or a more "elegant" variation:

*Find What*: `^(?=[0-4M]{4}$)[0-3M]*\K4`
*Replace with*: `2`

The point is that we need to make sure we only have a line that matches your criteria with the positive lookahead `(?=[0-4M]{4}$)` (it checks if a line has only 4 characters that are either digits or `M`), and then we *capture* the part before `4` into Group 1 (that will be later re-inserted into the result using `${1}` backreference), and `4` is just matched, not captured (see there are no `()` around it).

As you need to replace with a digit following a backreference, we need to enclose the Group ID inside the backreference with curly braces.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?=[0-4M]{4}$)` - there must be exactly 4 characters, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `M` up to the end of line
- `([0-4M]*?)` - Group 1 capturing zero or more allowed chars, but *as few as possible* up to the first
- `4`  - digit `4`.

In the alternative:

- `[0-3M]*` - matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `M`, zero or more times, up to the
- `\K4` - `4`, but all what was matched before `4` is omitted from the match, so we only need to replace with `2`.

**If you want to replace multiple `4`s, you may use this pattern variation**:

```
(?:^(?=[0-4M]{4}$)|(?!^)\G)[0-4M]*?\K4
```

Here, the `(?:^(?=[0-4M]{4}$)|(?!^)\G)` part will find the lines you need (or the end of the last successful match - `(?!^)\G`), then `[0-4M]*?` will again consume 0+ allowed characters, a few as possible, up to the first `4`, *but* `\K` will omit those consumed characters leaving just `4` in the match. So, the replacement will be just `2`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note that using this approach, you will only replace a single `4`, you will need to click *Replace all* several times to replace all those fours with twos. You may use `(?:^(?=[0-4M]{4}$)|(?!^)\G)[0-4M]*?\K4` and replace with `2` if you want to replace multiple.

Comment: Wow, thanks again! I'll try to learn what-is-what later, because it looks awesome!